# Heard process and AdvancedBlocking process on Ventura

Tags: macbook-pro, ventura

Heard process and AdvancedBlocking process on Venturayesterday I was looking at my console when I noticed the process called Heard, went to discussions.apple.com to formulate a question about it and try to learn but no one could told me about those AirPods connected on my computer when I never did have or own any of those... I keep bluetooth off and sometimes it is on without any authorization from my side, trying to look information about the process on the search engine another process called AdvancedBlocking popped up and honestly seems pretty shady cause in the apple site after I open another thread regarding this last process got my access denied to the thread... any ideas or help would be much appreciates... am I being listened? spied? what is all this?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not an indication of you being listened on, spied on, hacked or anything like that.

`heard` (which is to be read as hear-d for hear-daemon) is a part of the HearingCore framework, which is part of the standard installation of macOS.

The log texts you have included does not in any way indicate that AirPods have been connected to your computer. That is a misunderstanding on your part.

Comment: thank you! I understand It could have been a misunderstanding, just would like to understand why today the AirPods message did not showed up at all. Could you help me understanding what is advancedblocking as well? thanks in advance

Comment: Regarding why the AirPods message did not show up today: Because you did not have a similar route change today.

Comment: Regarding AdvancedBlocking: This is simply a program you have installed on your Mac.

Comment: what program? I haven't done any of that lately at all... do you have any idea which program would say that?

Comment: In general, one should not rely on their own interpretation of log messages found in Console unless they happen to be either a software developer, professional software tester, system administrator or professional IT-supporter.

Comment: @coyotesurf The text "AdvancedBlocking" is the name of the program (process) that has logged that message. You can search your Mac for that file if you want.

Comment: thank you! I get it now... thanks a lot for your help. I do not rely on the console messages Im just curious and this is how I learn. much appreciated.

Comment: That would be a terrible way to learn in my opinion. The console messages should be seen mainly as random texts from the brains of developers. Without context they are essentially meaningless. Instead the best way to learn the meaning of the message is to examine the source code of the program that produces the log (i.e. to get the context) - or if that is not available, then look at the code itself.

Comment: In that case you could learn for example that this message in particular comes from the fact that when you change audio routes, the system has also sort of functionality for owners of AirPods where they can for example temporarily share audio, automatically switch which of a number of pre-paired systems, they're connected to, etc. Developers then added added a check to see if this special functionality is indeed to be active now - and logged whether or not this was the case every time. For your system it is not the case that it is to be active. So that's logged. It's really harmless.